# Using Euler's formula to prove $\cos(2\theta)+\cos(4\theta)+\cdots+\cos(2n\theta)=\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\cos((n+1)\theta)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

there is this question in my assignment that i'm struggling to do, it says:

> Using Euler's formula, prove that:
> $$\cos(2\theta)+\cos(4\theta)+\cdots+\cos(2n\theta)=\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\cos((n+1)\theta)$$

I was unable to get anywhere with expanding the LHS, so i have attempted to arrive at the LHS starting from the RHS, and this is what i have got to so far:
$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$$
$$\sin(n\theta)=\frac{e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}}{2i}$$
$$\cos((n+1)\theta)=\frac{e^{i(n+1)\theta}+e^{-i(n+1)\theta}}{2}$$
and by multiplying the last two, then dividing by the second one, i arrived at:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{e^{i(2n+1)\theta}-e^{-i(2n+1)\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}-1)$$
and i am struggling to move any further than this, i assume there's an easier way to do this by starting from the LHS instead, but i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I would indeed recommend to start with the LHS and look for a geometric sequence waiting to be summed.

Comment: See [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/42969)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By Euler formula**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^n \cos (2 k \theta)&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{e^{2 k \theta i}+e^{-2 k \theta i}}{2} \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n e^{2 k \theta i}+\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-2 k \theta i}\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{e^{2 \theta i}\left(e^{2 n \theta i}-1\right)}{e^{2 \theta i}-1}+\frac{e^{-2 \theta i}\left(e^{-2 n \theta i}-1\right)}{e^{-2 \theta i}-1}\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{e^{(2 n+1) \theta i}-e^{\theta i}}{e^{\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}}-\frac{e^{-(2 n+1) \theta i}-e^{-\theta i}}{e^{\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}}\right]\\&= \frac{1}{2\left(e^{\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}\right)}\left[(e^{(2 n+1) \theta i}-e^{-(2 n+1) \theta i})-\left(e^{\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}\right)\right]\\&=\frac{1}{4 i \sin \theta}[2 i \sin (2 n+1) \theta-2 i \sin \theta]\\&= \frac{cos(n+1) \theta \sin (n \theta)}{\sin \theta}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Euler's formula:

> $$e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x.$$

This implies
$$e^{inx}= \cos(nx) +i \sin(nx)= (\cos x+ i \sin x)^n.$$

Observe that
$$ x^2+x^4+\dots+x^{2n} = x^2 \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^2-1}.$$

Set $x=e^{i\theta}$. We would then easily see that
$$\Re(LHS)=\cos(2\theta)+\cos(4\theta)+\dots+\cos(2n\theta), $$
where $\Re$ stands for real part.
Also see that

$$RHS = \frac{x^{2n}-1}{1-x^{-2}}=\left(\frac{\cos(2n\theta)-1+i\sin(2n\theta)}{1-(\cos(2\theta)-i\sin(2\theta))}\right),$$
as $x^{-2}=e^{-2i\theta} = \cos(2\theta)-i\sin(2\theta)$.

Reduce the right hand side to $a+ib$ form by multiplying and dividing by the conjugate of the denominator and using  the formulas $1-\cos2x= 2\sin^2x$ and formula of $\cos(A+B)$. You would then observe that
$$a=\Re(RHS) = \frac{\sin(n\theta)\cos((n+1)\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is rather easy to prove the identity using **Product-to-sum formula**.

Multiplying the sum by $2\sin \theta$ gives a telescoping series as
$$
\begin{aligned}
&2 \sin \theta[\cos (2 \theta)+\cos (4 \theta)+\ldots+\cos (2 n \theta)] \\
= & {[\sin (3 \theta)-\sin \theta]+[\sin (5 \theta)-\sin (3 \theta)]+\cdots+ [\sin (2 n+1) \theta-\sin (2 n-1) \theta] } \\
= & \sin (2 n+1) \theta-\sin \theta \\
= & 2 \cos (n+1) \theta \sin (n \theta)
\end{aligned}
$$
Re-arranging gives
$$
\cos(2 \theta)+\cos (4 \theta)+\cdots+\cos (2 n \theta)=\frac{\sin (n \theta) \cos (n+1)}{\sin \theta}
$$